# FB Login Function in Coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

How would I write the following in Coffeescript?

`$('#fb-login-button').click(function() {
  FB.login(function(response) { }, { scope:  $('#fb-login-button').data('fbScope') });
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this :

```
$('#fb-login-buton').click -> FB.login ((response) -> ), scope: $('#fb-login-button').data 'fbScope'
```

You can also check out the compiled code http://coffeescript.org/